# Azure app name reported as /subscription/guid/resourcegroups/appName/

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

In Azure Monitor's Logs query results some of the values for `appName` are reported as expected but some are reported as

```
/subscriptions/guid_here/resourcegroups/group_name_here/providers/.../app_name_here
```

Can I fix this (in the query or at the app settings)?

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of how both variants actually differ? Along with the details of the table/query involved?

Answer (score 1):

Identifying an application by name assumes uniqueness across all accessible subscription. If you have multiple applications with the specified name, the query fails to return expected result because of the ambiguity.

I think you are having multiple application with same name so it's returning **Azure Resource ID** identifier instead of what we are expecting.

Check the **Identifying an Application** section in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query#querying-across-log-analytics-workspaces-and-from-application-insights) for more information.

Because app names are not unique, this identifier might be ambiguous. It's recommended to use Qualified name, Workspace ID, or Azure Resource ID as the identifier.